# Differences between two URL formats in applets

Tags: java, url, applet

I have an `Applet` and when I use the `getCodeBase()` I get a plain URL that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/x/y/z/
```

I can use other `Applet` methods like `getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/img.gif")` to get resources (like an image in this case).

However, if I use `Applet.class.getResource("/images/img.gif")` I see URLs that look like this:

```
jar:http://localhost:8080/x/y/z/a/b/lib/myjar.jar!/images/img.gif
```

Is one way better than the other?  What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is classpath-relative. It means that `img.gif` is located within the jar file (and is found on the classpath of the applet jvm)

The former is a regular URL, and means that the gif file is present on the server at the given location.

They are used in different cases, so there's no "good or "bad" option. A thing to consider is: if you only need the image in the applet, you should place it in the jar rather than anywhere else on the server. (But this is not universal)

Comment: OK then if the client downloads the jar then they don't need to go back to the server to get resources, but a regular URL would have to go back to the server.  So when a browser encounters an Applet does it load the entire jar the Applet is in or just the classes it needs as it needs them?

Comment: it downloads the whole jar I think.